# Can you use hubot chatbot to ask multiple questions, remembering state to follow a script with multiple forks?

Tags: hubot, chatbot

For example if you had a question and script like

1. Are you over 13+

   a. if yes go to #2

   b. if no end
2. Please pick a chat room

Looking at hubot it looks like it looks for specific questions but doesn't necessarily store state or allow the progression of a longer interview by remembering previous answers and doing "if this then that".

Does hubot support this?  If not is there another open source alternative that is a better fit for the use case?

Would I just store user information in the hubot brain for each user's answer, building up a user's state over time?  I suppose with each user answer we can look up the user's state, and their current progression in the hubot brain and then handle it accordingly.

However, if it's more of a script rather than looking for any old random question via regex matching, does this take away from most of the benefit of using hubot in the first place?